# Guy accepts death penalty though he is innocent

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

About 10-15 years ago I watched a movie: there was a couple of anti death penalty activists. The woman dies, presumably murdered. The husband is charged and accepts the death penalty. After his execution a videotape of his wife committing suicide is released.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably looking for [The Life of David Gale](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289992/) (2003) starring Kevin Spacey and Kate Winslet:

> Dr. David Gale, an advocate of eliminating the death penalty, is accused of rape and murder. Once convicted, he ends up on death row in Texas himself, telling his story to a reporter through a series of flashbacks.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_of_David_Gale):

> Bloom pursues this lead until she finds a tape revealing that Harraway, who was suffering from terminal leukemia, had committed an elaborate suicide to look like murder. She and Wright are both seen on the videotape, showing that they framed Gale as part of a plan to discredit the death penalty.

Comment: Nailed it. That is the movie!